# OneToMany relationship and method to add an element in CLIPS

Tags: addition, one-to-many, clips

I need to model a OneToMany relationship in CLIPS.
I have ROOMS that may be related to a ZONE.
So I wrote:

```
(defclass ROOM (is-a USER)
(slot id
    (type SYMBOL))    
(slot zone
    (type SYMBOL)))


(defclass ZONE (is-a USER)
(slot id-zone
    (type SYMBOL))   
(multislot rooms
    (type INSTANCE) (create-accessor read-write))
(slot room-count
    (type INTEGER)))
```

As soon as I instance a new room, it should be added to a zone (if that room is associated to it).
I wrote this handler:

```
(defmessage-handler ZONE add-room-to-zone (?room)
(bind ?self:rooms ?room)   ;#1
(bind ?self:room-count (length$ ?self:rooms))
(printout t "Room [" ?room "] added to zone [" ?self "]" crlf)))
```

Rule that does the action is:

```
(defrule build-air-temperature-zone
?room <- (object (is-a ROOM) (id ?id) (id-zone ?id-zone-room))
(test (symbolp ?id))
?zone <- (object (is-a ZONE) (id-zone ?id-zone))
(test (eq ?id-zone ?id-zone-room))
=>
(send ?zone add-room-to-zone ?room)
```

If I instance multiple rooms I see only one instance add to my zone.
If think it's because #1 (inside the handler), it just set the room, and does not add it.

Is there a way to increment element in a multislot field?

Thanks 
Nic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your message-handler like this:

```
(defmessage-handler ZONE add-room-to-zone (?room)
  (bind ?self:rooms ?self:rooms ?room)   
  (bind ?self:room-count (length$ ?self:rooms))
  (printout t "Room [" ?room "] added to zone [" ?self "]" crlf))
```

Or this:

```
(defmessage-handler ZONE add-room-to-zone (?room)
  (slot-direct-insert$ rooms 1 ?room)
  (bind ?self:room-count (length$ ?self:rooms))
  (printout t "Room [" ?room "] added to zone [" ?self "]" crlf))
```